# Postgresql replication monitoring calculation

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have streaming replication running successfully, and would like to monitor it between master and slave. I know there are two values I can get on each:

```
 master:    select pg_current_xlog_location()
 standby:   select pg_last_xlog_receive_location()
```

However I'm not sure what to do with the hex value returned by either. Is this the size in bytes?? How do I calculate the difference? and what does that difference tells me?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `pg_current_xlog_location()` gives you a value like `64/A8EB6C20`, that means your xlog location is 64A8EB6C20 hexadecimal, which is effectively a byte number.  To calculate the difference, you can subtract the two values.  (For bizarre historical reasons, certain values in that sequence are skipped, but as long as you only compare for equality, you'll be fine.)

In PostgreSQL 9.2, you can use the function `pg_xlog_location_diff` to do all of this for you.

What do the numbers mean?  They are write-ahead log traffic.  Effectively, it's approximately the amount of data you write into the database.  You need to run your application and get a feeling for what values your setup can maintain and what is an appropriate lag.

Comment: Thanks Peter. So, should I subtract slave from master? am I correct in assuming that if the difference was 500, then that means the slave is 500 bytes behind the master?